# Web site causing browser to find the "wrong" screen width

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, media-queries

I have mobile optimised several sites in the same way using media queries - most are working fine on phones but two insist on always detecting a screen.width of 800px, no matter how small the actual device is.

Working correctly:
www.accountex.co.uk, www.legalex.co.uk, www.takeawayexpo.co.uk, www.streetfoodlive.co.uk

Detecting wrong screen size but only on mobile devices:

www.greatbritishbusinessshow.co.uk, www.bstartup.com

Even though the methods used are almost identical. The above two show correctly on all online mobile simulators, BUT use the media query for a screen width of 800px when loaded on actual mobile devices even when the device is 320x480 or otherwise very small.

Using console.log or alert these two sites always return 800px as the when alert(screen.width) is invoked - no idea how this can happen on a tiny device!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you don't show your code for doing the detection, we can't help you. Presumably your goal isn't just to get people to visit a bunch of sites, but this question is unclear and unanswerable without a lot more information and a lot fewer (read: zero) links.

Comment: while you're at it, you should specify what emulator or native device you're using.. and give a price tag (kidding)

Answer (score 2):

use this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Don't use snippets for things that don't run, just mark them up as code (see edit).